# How can I increment and decrement a value in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one value initially - let's call it x. Selecting the increment button should increase "+1" to the value. If I select decrement, x should decrease by -1.

However, what actually happens is that when I press the increment button, it increases +1 but if i click decrement, it decreases -2. It should only be increased/decreased by 1 value only. Also don't require continuous iteration (count++ and count--). it would be better if "count" is taken as variable inside .js file, not mentioning it in html as ng-init="count=15" .

[**JsBin**](http://jsbin.com/huyozapena/1/edit)

```
<div ng-controller="CounterController">
  <button ng-click="count = {{count}}+1" ng-init="count=15">
    Increment
  </button>
  count: {{count}}

  <button ng-click="count = {{(count) - 1}}">
    Decrement
  </button>
<div>
```

Comment: ng-click="count++" or ng-click="count--" :)

Comment: Does this incrementation `count++` work ? i've tried it without success :( only  `count = count +1` works

Comment: Try  `ng-click="count = count+1"` instead of `ng-click="count = {{count}}+1" ` as well with minus sign

Answer (score 9):

Simply this should work,

```
<div>
    <button ng-click="count = count+1" ng-init="count=15">
        Increment
    </button>
    count: {{count}}

    <button ng-click="count = count - 1">
        Decrement
    </button>
<div>
```

Comment: What do you mean iteration here?

Comment: i don't need count++ or count-- values. Exactly 1 value to be incremented or decremented.

Comment: @kriznaraj while decreament if I want to set condition as - **for decreament count should be always greater than 1.... if it is less than 1 then decreament should not work** for this, how should i add the condition on button

Comment: @ojuskulkarni just change the expression on decrement button to `count = count > 1 ? count - 1 : count`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because you using '{{' in ng-click, it's inserting value there, so after angular 'rendering', actual code looks like:

```
<div ng-controller="CounterController">
  <button ng-click="count = 15+1" ng-init="count=15">
    Increment
  </button>
  count: {{count}}

  <button ng-click="count = 15 - 1">
    Decrement
  </button>
<div>
```

but you want to work with reference. So just remove '{{' and '}}' and it will work.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/savovexare/1/ i'm not sure how to create a fork in jsbin, try this.

Comment: i don't need iteration.

Answer (score 3):

"Exactly 1 value to be incremented or decremented"

```
<div ng-controller="CounterController">
  <button ng-click="increment();">
    Increment
  </button>
  count: {{count}}

  <button ng-click="decrement();">
    Decrement
  </button>
<div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('CounterController', function($scope) {
  var incremented = false;
  var decremented = false;
  $scope.count = 15;

  $scope.increment = function() {
    if (incremented) { return; }
    $scope.count++;
    incremented = true;
  };
  $scope.decrement = function() {
    if (decremented) { return; }
    $scope.count--;
    decremented = true;
  };
});
```

If you want the user to be able to repeatedly do this, then...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('CounterController', function($scope) {
   $scope.count = 15;
   var max = $scope.count + 1;
   var min = $scope.count - 1;

  $scope.increment = function() {
    if ($scope.count >= max) { return; }
    $scope.count++;
  };
  $scope.decrement = function() {
    if ($scope.count <= min) { return; }
    $scope.count--;
  };
});
```

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8673/

Comment: You could combine those two methods if you want. i.e. pass a parameter to specify whether to increment or decrement.

Comment: if i first select increment. it shows 1, then decrement is not working.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted? Just use two guard variables instead. 2 secs..

Comment: this code works for only $scope.count = 0; this is not working for $scope.count = 15; variable can be of any number.

Comment: You'd need to change the max and min values as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66011/discussion-between-steven-keith-and-madhu-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample working code and caters to the following:
1) increases and decreases the counter by one
2) does not use continuous iteration
3) does not use ng-init
4) works for $scope.count = 15

(The replies already provided by Rasalom and smallatom helped and so did the link: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="count = count+1">
        Increment
    </button>
    count: {{ count }}

    <button ng-click="count = count-1">
        Decrement
    </button>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 15;
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```