# Operators Increment in AngularJS Expressions

Tags: angularjs

I using angularjs and in controller, I initialize a variable as following:

```
$scope.x = 0;
```

I want to increment variable x in html and  I write expression as following:

```
<div index = {{x++}}></div>
<a index = {{x++}}></a>
<b index = {{x++}}></b>
<p index = {{x++}}></p>
```

but isn't success
how can I do?

don't use ng-click, ng-repeat,...

Comment: What happens if you write like `<div index = {{x+1}}></div>` ?

Comment: thank, but i want to auto increment x, not only show x+1

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  This seems... *strange.*

Comment: This link could help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227535/how-can-i-increment-and-decrement-a-value-in-angularjs

Comment: oh, in this case, not use directives as ng-click, ng-repeat ...